# Divergence test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to prove that this is divergent

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

by finding the limit of

$$\ln \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

I know its $e$ and I am trying to arrive at that value by this

$$\ln y = n \ln(1 + \dfrac{1}{n})\\= \dfrac{\ln(1 + \dfrac{1}{n})}{\dfrac{1}{n}}$$

and I am already lost at this indeterminate form.

Comment: That quotient appears for example in the definition of the derivative, if you notice that $\ln 1 = 0$, and hence $$\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\ln 1}{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

Comment: Regardless of which series do you actually mean (with or without logarithm), terms do not tend to 0. Do you know some simple necessary condition for convergence of series?

Comment: @Daniel It's still an an indeterminate form from which I am lost at how can it proven equal to 1.

Comment: Can I make $$\ln (1 + \dfrac{1}{n}) = \ln (n + 1)$$?

Comment: @Ralf17 Either you know the derivative of $\ln$, in which case you know the limit is $1$, or you don't, in which case determining the limit will be hard. What definition of $\ln$ have you, if you don't know the derivative?

Comment: You have $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) = \ln (n+1) - \ln n$, if that helps you. But whether you can officially use that identity, I can't tell. Depends on what properties of logarithms are known.

Comment: I do not know this identity so I was tryng to do L'Hopitals. But I arrived at a function $$\dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}} (1 + \dfrac{1}{n})dx$$ that made me blank out.

Comment: Is it $\displaystyle\left[\ln\left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)\right]^{\,\,n}$ or $\displaystyle\ln\left(\left[1 + {1 \over n}\right]^{\,\,n}\right)$ ?.

Comment: the latter, but It was already solved thank for all those who help me figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \ln(x)$.  Then using the definition of the derivative, we have:

\begin{align*}
\ln\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)
\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) - \ln(1)}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&= f'(1)\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Alternatively, using L'Hopital's Rule, we have:

\begin{align*}
\ln\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)
\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{-1}{n^2+n}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2+n}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Note that being more rigorous with the computation of the limit in the above case (i.e., if you don't know L'Hopital's Rule or the computation of the derivative of the natural logarithm) is quite a bit more involved.  There is a third way to prove this which is even more advanced, which is to use the power series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ about $x = 0$.  But all of these depend on either knowing the derivative of $\ln(x)$ or more properties of the logarithm.  But assuming these issues are resolved, we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

Answer (score 2):

But if you want to prove that diverges is not most easy: 
$$\sum (1+1/n)\leq \sum (1+1/n)^n?$$

Comment: And the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Even easier: $1+\frac{1}{n} > 1$.

Comment: Oh is true you right.

Comment: But I was asked to use the divergence test.

Answer (score 1):

This is the indeterminate form $1^\infty$.

So set $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$
Then
$$\ln(L) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \ln{(1+\frac{1}{n})} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(1 + 1/n)}{1/n}$$

Apply L'Hopital's and then work backwards, solving for $L$.

Comment: L'Hospital is a bit circular, since that last limit is precisely the derivative of $\ln$ at $1$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dn} \ln(1+1/n) = \frac{-1/n^2}{1+1/n}$

Comment: Not really circular since you can show the derivative of log in some other way, if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}}= 1.\quad\mbox{So ?}.
\end{align}